# AngularJS passing nested array between multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, service

I have 2 controllers - ACtrl and BCtrl. Each of these Controllers are linked to 2 different templates and each template displays a series of data in a list.Each list-item also contains a button. I want to pass an nested array of coresponding data from the list-item to a 3rd controller DCtrl on ng-click of the corresponding list-item button.

I have learnt that we need to use Services to pass data between controller, but passing of nested array isn't very clear. Moreover, I a disply the data in the list-items within p tags and thus cannot rely on ng-model directive also.

Comment: What exactly *isn't very clear*? Use a service to store data and access it in your controllers, directives, whatsoever...

Comment: Why not Realize this ACtrl, BCtrl and DCtrl in a plunker and redefine the problem, technically..